# How to minimize the large space between menus and inline next to logo?

Tags: html, css, layout, navigation

I want to reduce the spacing of each menu or compress the image a little bit and inline it next to logo. What is the best way to do that?

[Here's my site](http://goo.gl/u7o6hS)

Here's the CSS of menu:

```
  .main-navigation.menu-right{
         text-align: right;
  #site-navigation .main-navigation .ak-container{
         padding: 0;
  .main-navigation .menu{
         display: block;
  .main-navigation ul {
         list-style: none;
         margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height:48px;
        font-size:18px;
        text-transform: initial;
        color:#ababab;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
.main-navigation a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
        padding: 0 18px;
}
```

Comment: Side note: try to avoid using `!important` and instead use selector specificity and cascading properly. It makes changing code later on much more difficult

Comment: To start out you need to put `#site-navigation` inside of `.ak-container`...

Comment: @ZachSaucier I put the #site-navigation like this #site-navigation .main-navigation .ak-container{ but nothings happen

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways you could solve this. The first as a commenter suggests is to start by putting your site-navigation inside your ak-container, so your HTML should be structured this way:

```
<div class="ak-container">
  <div class="site-branding">existing code</div>
  <div class="right-header clearfix">existing code</div>
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation menu-right">existing code</nav>
</div>
```

You should then have something along the lines of what you want, though you may have to play with the CSS just a little to get the exact look you desire.

Depending on what you want, and how your menu is coded, you may also need:

```
.sitebranding {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

You will need some testing if your site is responsive.

Comment: the structure now of the html is same as above and i put position: absolute;
  z-index: 1; in site-branding but it affects the responsive design when I resize it. Pls take a look and test it

Comment: with responsive design, you need to change your CSS for each media query. Easiest thing to do is set the position & z-index _only_ for desktop size.If you're having specific issues, then you can post another question to say "at this size, I want it to look like ..., and here's the code..."